# Is there an event fired when a Web Page element is manually deleted from the Browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

Manually deleting webpage html elements of poorly written websites has been one way I have been able to bypass restrictions on most websites. I need to also make such restrictions without logging out users to keep intruders restricted.

**What I'll like to do:** I'll like to logout the user after an interval of inactivity, but because data not saved might be lost in the process, I'll like to use a modal dialog to lock the screen and ask for the password without redirecting to a login screen
Here is an image below indicating what I mean:-

[image]

I'll like to know if there's an event fired by the browser when this is done. I saw on a website, once you inspect the browser page(open browser backend), it crashes the page, when the browser back end is closed it reloads.  I have no code to show because I didn't see any single code that has resolved this issue.

EDIT:- I finally found a code that does a bit of what I want, but I'll settle for an actual event than an infinite time to check if its opened or not.

```
var element = new Image;
var devtoolsOpen = false;
element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
    devtoolsOpen = true; // This only executes when devtools is open.
});
setInterval(function() {
    devtoolsOpen = false;
    console.log(element);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += (devtoolsOpen ? "dev tools is open\n" : "dev tools is closed\n");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: There is no event that gets fire when you delete the element using the developer tools of the browser. Please inform us your overall goal for doing it. It may help us to understand your requirements properly and we can try to provide you the suitable suggestions for it.

Comment: I'll like to logout the user after an interval of inactivity, but because data not saved might be lost in the process, I'll like to use a modal dialog to lock the screen and ask for the password without redirecting to a login screen.

Comment: Not sure how your new requirement is related to the delete event that you had mentioned before. In that situation, you can try to store the data temporarily for example in the local storage or in a session or you can try to save the data using your logic and then logout the user.

Comment: The new requirement is awesome too, but it would be more awesome if the elements in the browsers are never tampered with, which would be **unique** cause that is only when the function should fire. Using an infinite setInterval seems like it would cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to capitalize on the code above and made it more functional, now I can lock screen without files being lost or if an intruder is trying to delete from the inspect element, they are prevented, even if the page reloads, it remains locked prompting user to still log in. it's secure now. thanks